# Argo Notifications about condition already sent problem

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am new to Argo. We created notifications and some custom triggers.

For example, `OutOfSync`. in the `OutOfSync` trigger we used `oncePer` condition. Then some applications (we have more than 50 applications) can not receive out-of-sync notifications.

I checked the logs and I found:

```
time="2022-11-18T15:51:09Z" level=info msg="Notification about condition 'on-deployed.[0].y7b5sbwa2Q329JYH755peeq-fBs' already sent to '{slack argo-notifications}'" resource=argocd/app-test
```

Then, I removed `oncePer` condition, and it worked. When I configured our environment for the first-time, I choose `oncePer` for just one-time notification send because that's what I read argo notifications documents.

`oncePer` is important to control sending duplicate notifications.
E.g:
`oncePer: app.status.operationState.syncResult.revision`

Does anybody know this situation? is it essential for duplicate messages? because we don't have a duplicate notification problem.
But I am not sure our problem is really related to `oncePer`, It doesn't make sense to associate it with it.
And also, we flush all caches, we deployed `argo-server` and `argocd-notifications` many times. Did not help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue by now? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: The question is not clear, what is the issue exactly? can you share more details